# CircleCi 2.0: aws command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, circleci, migrate

I try to migrate circleci from v1.0 to v2.0.

First I can't install awscli but finally can install it with the code below but got another error that cannot found aws command.

```
version: 2
    jobs:
      build:
        docker:
          - image: circleci/node:8.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
  - save_cache:
      key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      paths:
        - node_modules
deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.9.1
steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      name: Install yarn
      command: yarn install
  - run:
      name: Install awscli
      command: |
        sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
        pip install 'pyyaml<4,>=3.10' awscli --upgrade --user
  - run:
      name: AWS S3
      command: aws s3 sync build s3://<URL> --delete

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

It show "aws: command not found". I'm not sure that I do something wrong or not but I want to know what's the problem and how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would rework your config. Each job should have a focus/point. For deployment for example, you don't need NodeJS, you need the AWS CLI so use an image for that.

```yaml
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: /home/circleci
          paths: project
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: cibuilds/aws:1.16.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - attach_workspace:
          at: /home/circleci
      - run:
          name: AWS S3
          command: aws s3 sync build s3://<URL> --delete

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following step (taken from their v2 docs);

```
steps:
  - run:
      name: Install PIP
      command: sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
  - run:
      name: Install awscli
      command: sudo pip install awscli
  - run:
      name: Deploy to S3
      command: aws s3 sync build s3://<URL> --delete
```

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try a step before `Install PIP` - i've updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

This method for installing awscli seems to work fine on a variety of systems. Tested on *circleci/openjdk:8-jdk*, requires no additional installation.

**Edit**
Seems that the node image lacks the installation of libpython-dev.

```
##################
# Install AWS CLI
##################

# For node images on Circle, install libpython-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libpython-dev

# Download awscli bundle
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"

# Unzip the downloaded bundle
unzip awscli-bundle.zip

# Run the install script and install to ~/bin/aws directory
./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
```

After that, to run awscli commands, specify the full path to the aws executable, for example:

```
~/bin/aws s3 ls
```

**Resources**

[Helpful thread GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2290)

[Example GitHub repository with Circle config on node:8.9.1](https://github.com/muhammed-sayadi/awscli-test-install-circleci-node-docker)

[The CircleCI builds](https://circleci.com/gh/muhammed-sayadi/awscli-test-install-circleci-node-docker)